# dlookup with multiple criteria give type mismatch error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

i tried to use dlookup with two criteria but it give type mismatch error. i dont think datatype is the problem since both criteria works well if i use dlookup with single criteria.

this one give type mismatch error:

```
DLookup("TotalPallets", "tblRegister", "[Department]='" & strD & "'" Or "[PTSNo]='" & strp & "'")
```

separated the criteria,this two works well:

```
DLookup("TotalPallets", "tblRegister", "[Department]='" & strD & "'")
DLookup("TotalPallets", "tblRegister", "[PTSNo]='" & strp & "'")
```

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had your quotes messed up. Try this.

```
DLookup("TotalPallets", "tblRegister", "[Department]='" & strD & "' Or '[PTSNo]='" & strp & "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

well this should do the trick.just add some double quotes

```
DLookup("TotalPallets", "tblRegister", "[Department]=""" & strD & """ And [PTSNo]=""" & strP & """")
```

Answer (score 0):

DLookup("TotalPallets", "tblRegister", "[Department]='" & strD & "' Or '[PTSNo]='" & strP & """")

Small mistake